# sql oracle sum valaues in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, pivot

im looking for solutions to my problem.

i have a query

```
select em_name, sum(abs_day_left)
from pp_employees,
     pp_types_abs,
     pp_abs 
where em_id = abs_em_id and abs_abs_id = abs_id and
      abs_kod in ('12','13','14','15')  
group by em_name
```

i want to make more columns with another abs_kod number (image attachment)
for example

second column
... abs_kod in
('656','44','323','33') 
third column
... abs_kod in
('63','55','565','556') 
and more..
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m30T0.png)
thanks for help and nice weekend

One more thing...

the formula counts days from the whole month
how to make it count correctly the days when it sets the parameters for the half month, for example from 1980-01-01 to 1980-03-15

thanks in advance
bob

Comment: Your `from` clause is referencing multiple tables but has no `JOIN`.  Something is amiss.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff the joinconditions are probably in the ```where```: ```em_id = abs_em_id and abs_abs_id```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff however, the use ```join``` is good practice, because you'll get a syntaxerror when the joincondition is ommitted. When using where to join, you won't get a syntaxerror but a cartesian product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    em_name, 
    sum(case when abs_kod in (12,13,14,15)   then abs_day_left end) abs_day_left_1,
    sum(case when abs_kod in (656,44,323,33) then abs_day_left end) abs_day_left_2,
    sum(case when abs_kod in (63,55,565,556) then abs_day_left end) abs_day_left_3
from pp_employees
inner join pp_abs on em_id = abs_em_id 
inner join pp_types_abs on abs_abs_id = abs_id
where and abs_kod in (12,13,14,15,656,44,323,33,63,55,565,556)
group by em_name
```

Notes:

- *always* use explicit joins instead of old-shool, implicit joins - I tried to fix this but I am unsure I did it correctly, for a reason that lies in the following point...
- *always* qualify the columns in the query with the table they belong to